# How to set camera parameters with Android Camera api while using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm building a visible light communication decoder app on android phone using OpenCV 3.4.0. The app will do some image processing on each frame, and decode bits realtime.

For my application, I want to set the exposure compensation as low as possible. I know that OpenCV doesn't provide functions to do this, so I need to use Camera api (or Camera2). I've tried the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    mOpenCvCameraView = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mOpenCvCameraView.enableFpsMeter();

    // Here's where I try to set exposure parameter for my camera
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setExposureCompensation(parameters.getMinExposureCompensation());
    parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.release();
}
```

and here is what I do in each each frame:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Point pt1 = new Point(1, 40);
    Scalar clr = new Scalar(255, 255, 0);

    Imgproc.putText(mGray, "Frame No. " + counter, pt1, Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, fontSize, clr, 2);

    counter ++;
    return mRgba;
}
```

However, the camera still auto adjust the exposure after I call the Camera api.

Any helps about how to call functions within OpenCV would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using? Have you looked at the [`VideoCapture::set`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/opencv/videoio/VideoCapture.html) method and [VideoCaptureProperties](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d)?

Comment: @zindarod I'm using OpenCV 3.4.0. VideoCaptureProperties look promising, but I couldn't find examples for android using those methods. Do you know of any tutorials? Thanks!